# send email with postfix and relay smtp.gmail

Tags: email, centos, smtp, postfix-mta

I would like send emails (with centos) using postfix and the gmail's smtp server (smtp.gmail.com). I followed some tutorials found on the Internet like https://charlesauer.net/tutorials/centos/postfix-as-gmail-relay-centos.php. I created a certificate whith openssl too.
Now, when i send an email (with the "mail" command), i can read at the end of my logs file (/var/log/maillog):

```
Jun 27 11:25:23 localhost postfix/smtp[24202]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.108]:587: Connection timed out
Jun 27 11:25:23 localhost postfix/smtp[24202]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c07::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
Jun 27 11:25:49 localhost postfix/qmgr[24032]: 186D61A0E6C: from=<user@localhost.localdomain>, size=705, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 27 11:25:49 localhost postfix/smtp[24226]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c07::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
Jun 27 11:25:53 localhost postfix/smtp[24202]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.109]:587: Connection timed out
Jun 27 11:25:53 localhost postfix/smtp[24202]: 31A721A0E71: to=<adresse@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=208, delays=148/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.109]:587: Connection timed out)
Jun 27 11:26:19 localhost postfix/smtp[24226]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.108]:587: Connection timed out
Jun 27 11:26:49 localhost postfix/smtp[24226]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.109]:587: Connection timed out
Jun 27 11:26:49 localhost postfix/smtp[24226]: 186D61A0E6C: to=<adresse@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=2253, delays=2193/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp.gmail.com[74.125.133.109]:587: Connection timed out)
```

"nc 74.125.133.108 587 -vv -w3" give me:

```
libnsock nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #1)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 74.125.133.108:587 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT TIMEOUT for EID 8 [74.125.133.108:587]
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

I think so that the relay has a good configuration (and postfix too) but the firewall prevent the link. Here is an extract of my configuration ("iptables -vnL"):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1673  125K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  21M 1986M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 3829  229K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
12405 2187K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
12405 2187K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:465 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:587 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
12405 2187K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   12   480 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
10843 2104K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
 
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
```

So, how can i configure the firewall in order to communicate with the gmail's relay for that emails arrive at destination ?
Thank you !

Comment: Nobody has an idea ?